# Recheck luggage at Paris CDG, possible with Indian passport and Canadian work visa?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, indian-citizens, canada, france

I am going from Delhi to Calgary via Paris on a self tranfer flight. Will have to collect and recheckin luggage. Is this possible with Indian passport and Canadian work visa itself? Or any other document or visa is required

Comment: Hello Akshay bro could you please respond if you were able to complete your journey? I am in a similar situation. Did Air India allow you to board at New Delhi? I’ll appreciate your response

Answer (score 5):

No, that’s not possible. You will need a visa to be able to go through border control, claim your luggage, and re-check it.

Transit without visa (TWOV) in CDG only works if you stay airside (“international area”). But even if you didn’t have checked luggage and did not need to go through passport control, it’s unlikely an airline would let you board the first flight without a visa for France, as in the case of separate tickets they would most likely consider that your final destination is France.

You’ll either have to apply for a visa, find a connecting flight (on the same ticket), or find another connection airport (I believe the UK could be an option, but that’s a topic for another question).

Answer (score 0):

I have asked Indian Airlines if I can board the said plain, as per them I can if i do not have check in baggage. This info i have gathered from there counter at Delhi airport. Also with westjet, as per them as well i can board from Paris, given that I remain at airside only. I don't think there should be any other issue now. is there?

Comment: Do you mean you're giving up on hold luggage and won't need to recheck luggage? This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Akshay Vip In your question you say that you will have to reclaim your luggage on arrival in  Paris and re-check it for your onbound flight. That means you *cannot* remain airside.  Please clarify your intentions regarding whether you will have checked-in luggage or not. For completeness it would also be helpful if you added your full itinerary details (airline, flight arrival times etc) to the question.

Comment: The part from Paris to Calgary only works if you can get your boarding pass while airside, i.e. can actually do mobile or online check-in or there are transfer desks in Paris which you can reach and can issue the boarding pass for you. But you should probably get written confirmation that they will let you board in Delhi. Many airlines or agents won’t take the risk of boarding a passenger without a connecting flight on the same ticket and without a visa. Have you considered what would happen if you missed your second flight? You would be a no show, and your ticket cancelled.

Comment: As per the scenario, i have decided not to travel with check in luggage. I personally went to the air India koisk at Delhi airport and they have confirmed that i can travel with the Canadian work visa, without check in luggage. They did it after amking a few calls.

Comment: I think i should not miss the 2nd flight as there is a 20 hr gap in between the both.

Comment: However, i do not have a written confirmation from air India. Should I get one ?